# share a global variable to a class in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developping an asp.net application. I have a page called "home.aspx" which contains 2 buttons called "button1" and "button2". Each button has a onclick method, respectively called "Button1_click" and "Button2_click". My goal is to share a common variable between these 2 methods, so basically I tried to add a property to the class associated to my page like this :

```
public partial class Home : Syste.Web.UI.Page
{
    private int myproperty=0;

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myproperty++;
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myproperty++;  
    }
}
```

With this code, I was thinking that the "private int myproperty=0" would be called only the first time I load and get to the page. And then when I would be on the page, if I click on button1 or button2 the myproperty would just be incrementated by one. But when I am debugging, I see that each time I click on button1 or button2 the "private int myproperty=0" is called again which I don't understand. Is anyone has a solution?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: asp.net classes like `Page` only exist for the lifetime of the request, each request creates a new instance. If you want to store information between requests you will have to persist it somewhere, if it is just in memory then `Session` is often used, but bear in mind each client will have their own session.

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET if you want use global variables you'll have to use the `Session` object(if the variable is different for every single user, like count how many time a user click a Button) or `Application` object(If the variable is common to all the users like count how much user visit your site).
Example:

```
//Set variable
Session["myVariable"] = value
//Get variable
var myVariable = Session["myVariable"]
```

The syntax is equal for `Application` just replace `Session` with `Application`

Answer (score 0):

Make your variable `static`

> Like this

```
    public partial class Home : Syste.Web.UI.Page
   {
    private Static int myproperty;

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //You can access myproperty here (same copy)
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //You can access myproperty here (same copy)
    }
}
```

Comment: What? Then what's the need of `Session` in ASP.NET?

Comment: session object  is for a user session level and application object is for all user or whole application and this is for the particular page level. It will share the same copy of data.

Comment: NO, that's a wrong way of doing. You should be using any state maintenance mechanism rather storing it in `static` variable. Consider reading more about this.

Comment: my answer was according to the question. I know it is not the good way of storing data.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Session as below

```
private int Count
{
  get 
   {
     if (Session["Count"] == null)
     {         Session["Count"] = 0; return 0;      }
     else 
        return (int)Session["Count"] ; 
   }
   set
   {
      Session["Count"] = value;
   }
} 

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)     
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
        Count = 0; 
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Count++; 
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Count++; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How you want to share the value of the variable myproperty?

-If you want to reuse the value of `myproperty` per window you need to store the value in the vewstate: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Another way is to use a asp.net webcontrol hiddenfiled to store the value.

-If you want to reuse the value for session, you can store the value in the session (Session["myproperty"])

-If you want to share the value with all the users you can use the application: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94xkskdf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

as Ben Robinson said you have to persist that value somewhere.
An easy way is to use Session:

1. Create a "const string" variable in the class to hold the session index like:

   const string MY_PROPERTY = "MyProperty";
2. then whenever you want to store or read the value use:

   //to store
   Session[Home.MY_PROPERTY] = int.parse(Session[Home.MY_PROPERTY])+1;
   //to read
   int myVariable = int.parse(Session[Home.MY_PROPERTY])

you can also create a property in your class like:

```
const string MY_PROPERTY = "MyProperty";
public int MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        if (Session[Home.MY_PROPERTY] == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            int iValue = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(Session[Home.MY_PROPERTY].ToString(), out iValue))
                return iValue;
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }
    set
    {
        Session[Home.MY_PROPERTY] = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the postback check, before the increment, can resolve the problem.
Add following code before increment.

```
if(!IsPostBack)
```